# Trying to scrape the entire content of a div

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, scrape

I have this project i'm working on and id like to add a really small list of nearby places using facebooks places in an iframe featured from touch.facebook.com I can easily just use touch.facebook.com/#/places_friends.php but then that loads the headers the and the other navigation bars for like messges, events ect bars and i just want the content.

I'm pretty sure from looking at the touch.facebook.com/#/places_friends.php source, all i need to load is the div "content" Anyway, i'm extremely new to php and im pretty sure what i think i'm trying to do is called web scraping.

For the sake of figuring things out on stackoverflow and not needing to worry about authentication or anything yet i want to load the login page to see if i can at least get the **scraper** to work. Once I have a working scraping code i'm pretty sure i can handle the rest. It has load everything inside the div. I've seen this done before so i know it is possible. and it will look exactly like what you see when you try to login at touch.facebook.com but without the blue facebook logo up top and thats what im trying to accomplish right here.

So here's the login page, im trying to load the div which contains the text boxes to login the actual login button. If it's done correctly we should just see those with no blur Facebook header bar above it.

I've tried

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://touch.facebook.com/login.php');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
      if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'login_form') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
?>
```

all that does is load a blank page.

I've also tried using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

and i modified the example basic selector to

```
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://touch.facebook.com/login.php');

foreach($html->find('div#login_form') as $e)
    echo $e->nodeValue;

?>
```

I've also tried

```
<?php
$stream = "http://touch.facebook.com/login.php";
$cnt = simplexml_load_file($stream);

$result = $cnt->xpath("/html/body/div[@id=login_form]");

for($i = 0; $i < $i < count($result); $i++){
    echo $result[$i];
}
?>
```

that did not work either

Comment: I could imagine this data to be available in JSON over FB's Graph API which would save you the scraping. Have you checked the API docs yet?

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm really hellbent on figuring this idea out. I've seen it done before and i really liked the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that you can't use the facebook API, if you can, then I strongly suggest you use it, because you will save yourself from the whole **scraping** deal.

To **scrape** text the best tech is using xpath, if the html returned by touch.facebook.com is xhtml transitional, which it sould, the you should use xpath, a sample should look like this:

```
$stream = "http://touch.facebook.com";
$cnt = simplexml_load_file($stream);

$result = $nct->xpath("/html/body/div[@id=content]");

for ($i = 0; $i < $i < count($result); $i++){
    echo $result[$i];
}
```

Comment: what you're saying makes sense. I changed a few typos and spaces,but i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 7. I'm not exactly sure what's going on in that part to really make any adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stream = "http://touch.facebook.com";
$cnt = simplexml_load_file($stream);

$result = $nct->xpath("/html/body/div[@id=content]");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
    echo $result[$i];
}
```

there was a syntax error in this line i removed it now just copy and paste and run this code

Answer (score 0):

**Scraping** isn't always the best idea for capturing data else where.  I would suggest using Facebook's API to retrieve the values your needing.  **Scraping** will break any time Facebook decides to change their markup.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about your comparison operators

`===` is for comparing strictly, you should be using `==`

```
if ($div->getAttribute('id') == 'login_form')
{

}
```